# Unity Android build error - There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

Seemingly out of nowhere I am hit with this error when attempting to build and deploy to my device:

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.collections@1.2.4\Unity.Collections\NativeList.cs(839,24): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'safety' of 'NativeArray<T>.ReadOnly.ReadOnly(void*, int, ref AtomicSafetyHandle)'
```

I can export an APK, but am not sure where this issue has come from. The logcat tool shows that the device is connected.

So far, I have searched the Unity forums, but the only page I could find [was this one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/it-seems-like-there-is-a-bug-in-nativelist-t-asparallelreader.993096/). However, this post relates to a Windows build.

EDIT:
After installing the manually exported APK file to my device, logcat is showing all sorts of issues. The game is completely broken as a result. They are all the same error, but different scripts/namespaces are referenced, and here is just one of them:

```
2023/06/22 16:59:59.703 4657 4786 Error Unity A scripted object (probably UnityEngine.UI.Image?) has a different serialization layout when loading. (Read 32 bytes but expected 136 bytes)
```

Comment: Did you change Unity versions at some point? I'd close Unity, delete the Library directory, then open Unity and wait for it to finish importing and see if you have any script errors. If you do, fix them. If not, try building for Android again.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have not updated Unity. I tried the usual steps when these things happened: deleting Library, full re-import, and dependency resolver. Throughout development, I ran daily builds and until today everything was fine...

Comment: If nothing changed, as verified by source control, then there shouldn't be a problem. Are you using asset bundles or addressables? Have you rebuilt them? A serialization error like that means that a file is corrupt or it was built using different code than the executable that is trying to load it.

Comment: Upon further investigation, a colleague updated a plugin through the package manager that wasn't causing issues before. But I noticed that it had Android-specific content inside it that had changed, so I reverted that commit, which thankfully fixed the issue and I can now make builds again. Thanks to your previous comment/suggestion I sanity-checked the commit log one more time. Many thanks for your help. If you wouldn't mind posting this as an answer I will gladly mark it as the solution.